# ExtJS GridPanel "show in groups" not displayed/ not working

Tags: extjs, extjs4, aem

I encountered some weird behavior on GridPanel feature of ExtJs. I have included a groupField config option and it is not displayed and as well not working. Maybe you guys can give me an idea why?

```
createStore : function(itemPath) {
                        return new 
                             CQ.Ext.data.GroupingStore({

                                 proxy : new CQ.Ext.data.HttpProxy(
                                            {
                                                url : "/bin/test/private/folder/check.json",
                                                method : "GET"
                                            }),
                                //method: "GET",
                                reader: new CQ.Ext.data.JsonReader({
                                        root: 'variables',
                                        fields: [
                                            {name: 'group', type: 'string'},
                                            {name: 'path', type: 'string'},
                                            {name: 'status', type: 'string'}
                                        ]
                                }),
                              updateData : function() {

                                    // request the data 
                                    this.load({
                                        params : {                  
                                            path : itemPath         
                                        }
                                    });
                                },
                                sortInfo: {field: 'path', direction:'ASC'},
                                groupField: 'group',
                                groupOnSort: true,
                                autoLoad : true
                         });
                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your groups to be displayed in the grid panel, you also need to add the [grouping feature](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping) to your grid.

Answer (score 0):

Where is updateData coming from?  I am not seeing it in the documentation anywhere.  Is that piece of code causing the issue?

Here is the example from Sencha: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/grid/grouping.html

Make sure you are viewing the 3.4 documentation too.